# unable to upload image throuth Ajax and firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to upload and image via Ajax to an php script but i have this Exception from Firefox !!

> An error has occurred making the request: [Exception... "'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "available"' when calling method: [nsIInputStream::available]"  nsresult: "0x80570030 (NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED)"  location: "JS frame :: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js :: .send :: line 8526"  data: no]

And here My Ajax Code :

```
"Save": function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
            timeout:30000,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'action':'update_mini',
                'postdata': JSON.stringify(new FormData(document.getElementById("mini_form"))),//jQuery('#mini_form').serialize(),
                'block': jQuery.urlParam('block')
            },
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',        
            cache:false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,                                
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)  {
                alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown)
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);                                        
                //jQuery("#mDialog").hide();
                //jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
    });
```

And the Html Form Code :

```
<form id="mini_form" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Option Name :</label><br><input id="option" name="option" type="text"/>M<input id="m" name="m" class="minifield" type="text"/>P<input id="p" name="p" class="minifield" type="text"/><br>
 Image: <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try commenting out some code, to see what rises this error, after finding it, update question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17803640/3340665

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one by putting your parameters to formdata.

```
if (window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData();

    finput = document.getElementById("fileupload-input");
    file = finput.files[0];

    if (file && !!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
        if (formdata) {
          formdata.append("image", file);

          upSuccess = true;

          jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(e){
                if (e == 'error'){ //an error occurred in server side script
                    alert('An error occured while uploading the image.');
                    upSuccess = false;
                }
            }
          });

          if (upSuccess == false){
            return;
          }
        }

    } 

}
```